# Storing an object in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to link the trainee object with the training session object, but this error shows up: `TrainingSession cannot be converted to TrainingSession[]` (it's in the last line).

I can't use an array list or anything similar because I have to follow the UML diagram in the assignment. I have used the following variables `sessionName`, `traineeNo`, and `sessionNo` to know which trainee and training session I'm dealing with.

```
public class Trainee extends Person {

    private TrainingSession [] ST;

    public TrainingSession [] getST() {
        return ST;
    }

    public void setST(TrainingSession [] ST) {
        this.ST = ST;
    }
}

public class TrainingSession {

    private int trainingSessionID;

    public int getTrainingSessionID() {
        return trainingSessionID;
    }

    public void setTrainingSessionID(int trainingSessionID) {
        this.trainingSessionID = trainingSessionID;
    }
}

public class TMS2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {

        File file = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
        Trainee [] trainee = new Trainee[15];

        int traineeID = read.nextInt();
        int trainingSessionID = read.nextInt();

        String sessionName = TrainingSession(trainingSession, trainingSessionID);
        int traineeNo = TraineeNo( trainee,  traineeID);
        int sessionNo = SessionNo( trainingSession,  sessionName);

        trainee[traineeNo].setST(trainingSession[sessionNo]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`trainingSession[sessionNo]`  is a `TrainingSession` object, not an array.

Perhaps you're looking for something like...

```
trainee[traineeNo].setST(new TrainingSession[] { trainingSession[sessionNo]});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Now how do I get the trainingSessionID from the ST object with a specific index so I could print it out?

Comment: umm.. `trainee[traineeNo].getST()[0].getTrainingSessionID()` ?